# Google drive pdf not uploaded properly to s3 server

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, google-picker

I am trying to upload the pdf file from google drive to s3 server, but its not uploaded properly.

I use google drive picker for get the file
Here is my

**Here is my google drive picker code:- (Client side code)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
        // Replace with your own Browser API key, or your own key.
        var developerKey = 'XXXXXXXXXX_ff_NX66eb-XXXXXXXXXXX';

        // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
        var clientId = "XXXXXXXXXX-hs4ujaro5sc3d0g8qndtcq2tl279cfm1.apps.googleusercontent.com"

        // Replace with your own App ID. (Its the first number in your Client ID)
        var appId = "XXXXXXXXXX";
        // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
        var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

        var pickerApiLoaded = false;
        var oauthToken;

              $scope.addGoogleDriveFile = function() {
                 if (!isValidSelectedCategories(getSelectedCategories())) {
                    return;
                }
                 if (!isValidSelectedCategoriesNoapost(getSelectedCategories())) {
                    return;
                }

                gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
                 gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});      
                  }

    function onAuthApiLoad() {
                     window.gapi.auth.authorize(
                         {
                           'client_id': clientId,
                           'scope': scope,
                           'immediate': false
                         },
                         handleAuthResult);
                   }

                    function onPickerApiLoad() {
                      pickerApiLoaded = true;
                      createPicker();
                    }

                    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
                      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
                        createPicker();
                      }
                    }

                    // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
                    function createPicker() {
                      if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
                        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
                        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                            .setAppId(appId)
                            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                            .addView(view)
                            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
                            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                            .build();
                         picker.setVisible(true);
                      }
                    }

                // A simple callback implementation.
                function pickerCallback(data) {
                  if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                      console.log(data);
            addGoogleDrivePDF (data.docs); 

                  }
                }

 var addGoogleDrivePDF = function (file) {
var pdfData = {
                url: file[0].url
            };

$http.post('/uploadto/s3/drtivepdf', pdfData )
                            .success((function (article) {
                                console.log(article);
                            }).error(function (error) {
                                console.log(article);
                            });

}
```

**Here i am able to get the file url**

> Like :
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39VaBFZeygDNEVuWDYtYlgxNGhTeVdKNWtSX0tpT0FzeDRB/view?usp=drive_web

**Here is my server side code**

**s3upload_rou.js file (router file)**

```
app.post('/uploadto/s3/drtivepdf', function (req, res, next) { 
          next();
        }, bookmark.addGoogleDrivePDF );
```

**s3upload_ctrl.js file (controller file)**

```
 var async = require('async');
       var config = require('../config');
       var file = require('../libs/file');

        exports.addDropboxBookmark = function (req, res, next) {
         saveGoogleDrivePdf(req.body.url, function (err, pdfDetail) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        cb(err);
                                    } else {
                                   res.send(pdfDetail);
                                    }
                                });
        }


        var saveGoogleDrivePdf= function (url, callback) {
            async.waterfall([
                function (cb) {
                    var fileDetails = {
                        url: url,
                        name: 'drive/' + url.toString().replace(/^(http|https):\/\//i, ""),
                        contentType: 'application/pdf'
                    };
                    file.uploadPdf(fileDetails);
                    cb(null, fileDetails);
                },function (fileDetails, cb) {
                    console.log(fileDetails);
                    //create object for saving the pdf 
                    var pdfDetail = {
                        pdf_url: fileDetails.url,
                        pdf_title: 'PDF FILE',
                        pdf_preview_image: config.defaultPreviewImageUrl,
                        pdf_file: fileDetails.name,
                        pdf_website: url.parse(url, false, true).host,
                        mode: 'pdf'
                    };
                    cb(null, pdfDetail );
                }
            ], function (err, pdfDetail ) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    callback(null, pdfDetail );
                }
            });
        }
```

**Here is my file.js code:-'**

```
var request = require('request');
        var config = require('../config');
        var url = require('url');
        var http = require('http');
        var pool = new http.Agent();
        var streamingS3 = require('streaming-s3');
        exports.uploadPdf = function (details, cb) {
            var options = {
                url: config.s3.url + 'upload/drive',        
                method: 'POST',
                json: true,
                body: details,
                headers : { "x-api-key": config.s3.apiKey, "x-aws-bucket": config.aws.bucket, "Content-Type": 'application/json' },
                agent: pool
            };
            request(options, function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    logger.log('error', "PDF Error: ", { error : err , details: details });
                } else {
                    console.log(res.body);
                    logger.log('info', "UPLOAD PDF", { response : res.body });
                }
            });
        };
```

Uploading is working fine, but when i am trying to view that file on S3, i am not able to open it.

Any reason ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try by passign this link 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39VaBFZeygDNEVuWDYtYlgxNGhTeVdKNWtSX0tpT0FzeDRB/view?alt=media

Answer (score 0):

To download the selected file with JS, use this

```
function downloadFile(file, callback) {
  if (file.downloadUrl) {
    var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      callback(null);
    };
    xhr.send();
  } else {
    callback(null);
  }
}
```